Java On An Android Phone
I'm programming USING JVDROID on my Android phone. The problem is that my phone doesn't seem to have the basic libraries needed for the imports.

How do I import the libraries?
If anyone programs Java on their phone, do you have any suggestions or tips?

Thank you.
I have tried searching for the libraries on Google to no avail.

Just curious but... why?

I live and travel in an RV. Setting up my full computer is often not possible. I still world like the ability to write some routines for my convenience in using my phone..
